# Why does the CSS not work with my button element?

Tags: html, css, button, audio, static

As seen in the example below, my CSS for the button does not work, and the button for my audio has stock CSS.
I have tried using #div-1 and .div-1 in the external css file, along with messing around with the divs.

I don't have very much experience in html, so any extra help with my code is welcome!

Thanks for the help :)

```js
var x = document.getElementById("audio"); 

function playAudio() { 
  x.play(); 
} 

function pauseAudio() { 
  x.pause(); 
}
```

```css
#title {
    Font-size:70px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    color: #008eb0;
}

#p {
    Font-size:13px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #008eb0;
    text-align:center;
    top:1000px
}

body {
    background-color:white;
}

.div-1{
    border-radius: 3px;
    color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding:5px;
    top:100px;
}

.div-2 {
    border-radius: 10px;
    color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.555);
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    }


}

#div1 {
    font-style: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet"
type = "text/css"
href = "style.css">
<div id = "title">
    <h>Title</h>  
</div>
</head>

<body>
    <div id = "p">
        <p>subheading</p>
    </div>
 </body>



<audio id="audio">
  <source src="not sure yet" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="not sure yet" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
    <div class="div-1">
        <button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play</button>
    </div>
    <div class="div-2">
        <button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause</button> 
    </div>

<div1>
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="25">_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________</marquee>
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="right" scrollamount="25">________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________</marquee>
</div1>



</html>
```

Comment: The <marquee> tag is deprecated. It may break things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple reasons your CSS for buttons isn't working:

**1. Your HTML structure is kind of jacked up.**

Generally, information about your page (title that appears in browser tabs, meta data, links to JS and/or CSS files, etc.) go in the HEAD element; and the content of your page goes in the BODY element. (More here: [MDN Intro to HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Getting_started#anatomy_of_an_html_document))

**2. None of your CSS selectors actually target the BUTTON elements.**

I'm assuming you'd like these CSS rules to apply to the button elements in side of the div-1 and div-2:

```
.div-1 {
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
    top:100px;
}

.div-2 {
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.555);
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

These rule will only apply to the DIV with these classes on them. You'd either want to change these selectors to include the buttons:

```
// Either add the buttons to the existing CSS...
.div-1 button {}
.div-2 button {}

//....or add classes to the buttons in the HTML and change the selectors in your CSS
.button-1 {}
.button-2 {}
```

**Oh, almost forgot...**

It looks like you might have an extra closing curly bracket after the .div-1 CSS declaration in your code snippet. (In case that's not just a typo from entering the code snippet here...)

Hopefully that makes sense. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Makes much more sense now. I'll be sure to change the formatting too, thanks for the tip!

Comment: You're welcome. I forgot to add a link to it, but I pulled your code (minus the HEAD and outer BODY html tags) into Codepen, if you wanted to see more details on what I was talking about: https://codepen.io/code-and-pixels/pen/LYbBdJK?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have given the div1 two times for styling with . and # so you could write

```css
.div-1 {
    border-radius: 3px;    
    color:rgb(0, 0, 0);    
    font-style: italic;    
    text-align: center;    
    position: relative;    
    padding:5px;    
    top:100px;    
    font-style: bold;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the class on the `button` - for ex. `.div1 button {...}`

You can click on on the `Run Code Snippet` to the the `CSS` getting applied.

```css
#title {
    Font-size:70px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    color: #008eb0;
}

#p {
    Font-size:13px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #008eb0;
    text-align:center;
    top:1000px
}

body {
    background-color:white;
}

.div-1 button{
     border-radius: 3px;
    color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding:5px;
    top:100px;
}

.div-2 button{
    border-radius: 10px;
    color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.555);
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
  }


}

#div1 {
    font-style: bold;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <div id="title">
    <h>Title</h>
  </div>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="p">
    <p>subheading</p>
  </div>


  <audio id="audio">
    <source src="not sure yet" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="not sure yet" type="audio/mpeg" />
  </audio>
  <div class="div-1">
    <button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play</button>
  </div>
  <div class="div-2">
    <button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    var x = document.getElementById("audio");

    function playAudio() {
      x.play();
    }

    function pauseAudio() {
      x.pause();
    }
  </script>
  <div>
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="25">_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________</marquee>
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="right" scrollamount="25">________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________</marquee>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Legend! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is coding structure are not properly. I changed coding structure

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="title">
        <h>Title</h>
    </div>

    <div id="p">
        <p>subheading</p>
    </div>

    <audio id="audio">
        <source src="https://assets.codepen.io/3/jingle-bells.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
        <source src="https://assets.codepen.io/3/jingle-bells.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <div class="div-1">
        <button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play</button>
    </div>
    <div class="div-2">
        <button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause</button>
    </div>
    <div1>
        <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="25">
            _________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
        </marquee>
        <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="right" scrollamount="25">
            ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
        </marquee>
    </div1>

    

    <script>
        var x = document.getElementById("audio");

        function playAudio() {
            x.play();
        }

        function pauseAudio() {
            x.pause();
        }
    </script>


</body>


</html>
```

**Here is your CSS**

```
#title {
    Font-size: 70px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #008eb0;
}

#p {
    Font-size: 13px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #008eb0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 1000px
}

body {
    background-color: white;
}

.div-1 {
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
    top: 100px;
}

.div-2 {
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.555);
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Hey, so I'm not familiar with JS at all, what are you referencing with src under <!--- JS Vendor ---!> ?

Comment: ignore this think , I am using for my demo